# Encrypted message

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, oop

I just started to practice my coding skills (as a beginner) on Coding Game. I have this example:

Let’s take a simple example with a message which consists of only one character: Capital C. C in binary is represented as 1000011, so with this method, this gives:

0 0 (the first series consists of only a single 1)
00 0000 (the second series consists of four 0)
0 00 (the third consists of two 1)

So C is coded as: 0 0 00 0000 0 00

Second example, we want to encode the message CC (i.e. the 14 bits 10000111000011) :

0 0 (one single 1)
00 0000 (four 0)
0 000 (three 1)
00 0000 (four 0)
0 00 (two 1)
So CC is coded as: 0 0 00 0000 0 000 00 0000 0 00

```
public void Solution()
        {
            string MESSAGE = "C";

            List<int> codeAsc = new List<int>();
            string toBinary = "";
            string result = "";


            foreach (char c in MESSAGE)
            {
                codeAsc.Add(c);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < codeAsc.Count; i++)
            {
                toBinary += (Convert.ToString(codeAsc[i], 2));

            }

            int cnt = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < toBinary.Length-1 ; i++)
            {

                if (toBinary[i] == toBinary[i + 1])
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cnt == 1)
                    {
                        if (toBinary[i] == '1')
                        {
                            result += " " + "0 0" + " ";
                        }
                        else if (toBinary[i] == '0')
                        {
                            result += " " + "00 0" + " ";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (toBinary[i] == '1')
                        {
                            result += " " + " 0" + " " + new string('0', cnt) + " ";
                        }
                        else if (toBinary[i] == '0')
                        {
                            result += " " + "00" + " " + new string('0', cnt) + " ";
                        }
                       
                    }

                }

            }

            if (toBinary.Length - 1 == '1')
            {
                result += " " + "0 0" + " ";
            }
            else if(toBinary.Length - 1 == '0')
            {
                result += " " + "00 0" + " ";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

For letter C my code returns " 0 0  00 0000 " and it should be "0 0 00 0000 0 00". To be honest I don't get it why.

Comment: "so with this method" - what method?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your program one line at a time. That will show you what it is actually doing, rather than what you wanted it to do.

Comment: @StefanFFM - read it again: this method to encrypted the message: 0 0 (the first series consists of only a single 1); 00 0000 (the second series consists of four 0); 0 00 (the third consists of two 1)

Comment: @rossum Tbh I did it, but I just dont get it why it doesnt count the last 2 pair of 1.

Comment: One problem is the main for loop as it is not handling the final character of the binary encoded message. However, modifying the for loop to include the final character causes a run time error as the code attempts to compare the final character with the next character in the encoded message, which obviously isn't there! I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, your problem is comparing the current character in the binary encoded message with the next character. Doing this means you either cannot process the last character, or, if you do, you try and compare the last character with the next character, which can't exist.

A solution is to "pre-process" the first character in the encoded message then iterate over the remaining characters comparing with the previous character. This way you can iterate over all the characters in the message and be sure you don't attempt to access a character outside the confines of the encoded message.

Here is one solution:

```
public void Solution()
{
    string message = "C";
    string toBinary = "";
    string result;

    // Note: The binary encoding can be done in one loop. No need for an intermediary list.
    foreach (char c in message)
    {
        toBinary += Convert.ToString(c, 2);
    }

    // Pre-process the first character in the binary encoded string.
    var previousDigit = toBinary[0];
    if (previousDigit == '1')
        result = "0 0";     // Represents a single 1.
    else
        result = "00 0";    // Represents a single 0.

    // Iterate over the remaining characters comparing with the previous character
    // on each iteration. This way you will remain within the confines of the string.
    for (int i = 1; i < toBinary.Length; i++)
    {
        var thisDigit = toBinary[i];        // Get the next digit in the binary encoded string.
        if (thisDigit == previousDigit)     // If the digits are the same add a zero to increment the count.
        {
            result += "0"; 
        }
        else                                // If this digit is different to the previous one...
        {
            result += " ";                  // ...then add a space...
            if (thisDigit == '1')           // ..and add the appropriate encoding.
                result += "0 0";            // Represents a single 1.
            else
                result += "00 0";           // Represents a single 0.
        }

        previousDigit = thisDigit;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

And here is another, tidied up with more descriptive variable names, ternary operators to replace the `if`...`else` statements and made into a method so you can call it with any message you wish to encode:

```
public static class Encoder
{
    public static string Encode(string message)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) return "Message is null or empty.";

        var binaryEncodedMessage = string.Empty;
        
        foreach (var character in message)
        {
            binaryEncodedMessage += Convert.ToString(character, 2);
        }

        // Pre-process the first character in binary encoded message
        // and add the appropriate encoding to the result.
        var previousBinaryDigit = binaryEncodedMessage[0];
        var result = previousBinaryDigit == '1' 
            ? "0 0"     // Represents a single 1.
            : "00 0";   // Represents a single 0.

        // Iterate over the remaining binary digits comparing with the previous digit
        // on each iteration. This way you will remain within the confines of the string.
        for (var binaryDigitIndex = 1; binaryDigitIndex < binaryEncodedMessage.Length; binaryDigitIndex++)
        {
            var thisBinaryDigit = binaryEncodedMessage[binaryDigitIndex];    // Get the next digit in the binary encoded string.
            result += thisBinaryDigit == previousBinaryDigit
                ? "0"                      // If the digits are the same add a zero to increment the count.
                : thisBinaryDigit == '1'   // else add a space and the appropriate encoding.
                    ? " 0 0"
                    : " 00 0";

            previousBinaryDigit = thisBinaryDigit;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You would use the above as follows:

`Console.WriteLine(Encoder.Encode("C"));`

Comment: Didn't think about the "pre-process" the first character. Really thank you for help and especially for your comments for a better understanding the lines of code. Again, thank you so much @swatsonpicken.  It is really nice to know, as a beginner, there is somebody kind to give a piece of advice/hint. Have a nice day.